# How do I set permanent IP for my VirtualBox using Bridge adapter?

Tags: virtualbox, bridge

I'm running a web (development) server on my Virtualbox (Ubuntu 11.1).
I'm moving around a lot and thus I get various IP addresses on my computer.

Each time I get a new IP adr I have to change various config settings to get my site up and going.

Is there a way that I can set "permanent" IP address on my VB and somehow route all trafic to my laptop?

Comment: Is this not just a case of setting a staic IP in the Ubuntu Guest?

Comment: no, because I need to get out on the net from the dev server.

Comment: Please explain which config settings you need to change.  You should be able to achieve what you need with DNS.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem (VirtualBox 4.1.10, Host Ubuntu 11.10, Guest Ubuntu 11.10). Here's how I fixed it:

Set two network interfaces for the VM. The first one should be NAT and the second should be Host-Only. If you can't add a host-only connection, make sure you've set one up in Preferences -> Network.

In the Guest OS (Ubuntu for me), edit `/etc/network/interfaces`, adding the following on the end:

```
auto eth1 # this refers to the Host-only network interface
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.10 # Arbitrary IP address
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and reboot. And that's it. Don't modify anything for `eth0`, since we need that getting it's settings automatically via DHCP to access the internet. `eth1` lets the host and guest communicate with eachother.

Answer (score 4):

You can change your VB Guest IP to static by modifying these files.

```
vim /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add these lines at the end:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

For DNS Setting

```
vim /etc/resolv.conf
```

and add:

```
nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```